# How to extends an object with class in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to cleaning my ES6 class definition, I have this kind of code now:

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor({a, b, c, d, e}) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
    this.e = e;
    // some codes here
  }
  // some methods here..
}
```

This code extends everything passing to the constructor.

I use it in this way:

```
var obj = new SomeClass({a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5});
```

When I want to change the parameter passing to the constructor, such as:

```
var obj = new SomeClass({a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6});
```

I want `obj.f` to be `6`.

I want the constructor to be reusable if I am passing different params to it. If the params passing to the constructor changes, the return value changes.

I tried this:

```
class SomeClass extends Object {
  constructor(params) {
    super(params);
    // some codes here
  }
  // some methods here..
}
```

but this does not work.

So why this does not work?  If I extends the `Object` class, why `super({a:1})` does not return `{a:1}`?

```
$ node
> new Object({a:1})
{ a: 1 }
> class MyClass extends Object {
... constructor(params) { super(params); }
... }
undefined
> new MyClass({a:1})
MyClass {}
```

And how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand your need, but it seems like somthing simple like this should suit your needs:

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor(obj) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
    // some codes here
  }
  // some methods here..
}
```

That way

```
var obj = new SomeClass({a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6});
```

works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Think you probably want something like:

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor(o) {
    Object.assign(this, o);   
  }  
}

console.log(new SomeClass({a:1}))
console.log(new SomeClass({a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5}))
```

Answer (score 1):

As other people noted, using `Object.assign` would solve your case and not extending from Object.

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor(obj) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);   
  }  
}


console.log(new SomeClass({a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6}))
```

As for the answer, when you call `super(params)` in a class extended by a Object, you are calling the constructor of Object, which doesn't have parameters.

When you use `new Object({a:1})` you are calling a method and not a constructor.

It was confusing to me at first too and I had to research for it.

***Reference and more info here:***

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-object-constructor

Answer (score 0):

We can use spread operator to get rest of arguments.

Example :

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor({a, b, c, d, e, ...rest}) { 
    console.log(rest);
  }
}
```

here rest variable will have rest of all aruments can be n.

and you can with

```js
var obj = new SomeClass({a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6, g: 7});
```

i hope this help you

Comment: Hi, but how to set `f` in `rest` to `this.f`?

Comment: @cmal just access by rest.f or rest.g and assign respectively. like this.f = res.f;